# The M-theory to understand black holes

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, radio-astronomy, observational-astronomy

I am a layman in astronomy. Can someone please explain it to me whether the M-theory can be used to explain what is happening in the centre of the black hole where the singularity exists? Or is it still necessary to peek inside a black hole to gain that information?

Comment: I suspect that an M-theory description of a black hole could fill a few books, and perhaps win a Nobel. I think this makes it too broad.

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone please explain it to me whether the M-theory can be used
>   to explain what is happening in the centre of the black hole where the
>   singularity exists?

In Layman astronomy - yes, M-Theory (and probably a few string theories) do explain in detail what happens at the singularity, but it's a mathematical construct, not a testable hypothesis, so what it tells you might be wrong and little more than creative but irrelevant mathematics.

Looking inside a black hole, well, that's not a good idea either.  Even if you were able to see what happened, you wouldn't be able to send a message back telling anyone, so that's also no help.

Quantum physics is all a model anyway, but it's a **good** model because it provides accurate answers and it predicted the existence of particles that were later discovered.   Relativity is a good model too that stood up to testing.   Good models are useful and highly accurate and provide answers.

M-theory is a mathematical construct.  That's a different thing entirely.   It could still end up being right, but until it's testable, it's really just a mathematical exercise.   They really shouldn't call it a theory, it should be M-Hypothesis and String-Hypothesis.  They aren't real theories.

If I may quote Shakespeare from Henry IV, just for fun:

> GLENDOWER
>
> ```
> I can call spirits from the vasty deep.
> ```
>
> HOTSPUR
>
> ```
> Why, so can I, or so can any man;
> But will they come when you do call for them?
> ```

I'm personally much more comfortable with the "*both accepted theories, relativity and quantum theory, break down at the singularity, so we don't know what happens*".

If you prefer that M-Theory says what happens, preferring that answer is entirely optional, but I think the majority of people in this field are more comfortable with the we don't know answer.